# flexslider item width not working with riotjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider, riot.js

I am trying to achieve flexslider on in riotjs app. The slider is working fine but when I set custom item width for the slider, it doesn't. According to docs, it is supposed to work.

```
self.on('updated', function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
//                itemWidth: 210,
//                itemMargin: 5,
            controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
            start: function (slider) {
            $('.total-slides').text(slider.count);
            },
            after: function (slider) {
            $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide);
            }
    });
});
```

riot component:

```
<rsc-component id="dropBox" class="mybox col-lg-12">
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="../images/slide1.jpg" alt=""/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="../images/slide2.png" alt=""/>
            </li>
       </ul>
  </div>
</rsc-component>
```

Comment: Would it work if you delete `col-lg-12` class from your riot component?

Comment: @attomos No it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Give you flexslider a name, and refer to it internally, rather than hunting for it using jquery.

```
<rsc-component id="dropBox" class="mybox col-lg-12">
  <div class="flexslider" name="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">...</ul>
  </div>
<script>
...
//store reference to flexslider 
this.on('mount',function(){
this.$flexslider = $(this.flexslider); // from the name property in template
});

this.on('updated',function(){
 // I would have at a guess that the flexslider needs to recalc itself, so 
 // destroy it and regenerate.
 this.$flexslider.detach().flexslider({...})
}); 

</script>
</rsc-component>
```